# swift URLSession response data audio file saving and playing

Tags: swift, audio, request, response

I have some issue to save and play audio file from the response data of `URLSession` request. How can I play the audio file from response data?

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {data, response, error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error:", error)
        }
        if let response = response {
             print("Voice Response:", response)
        }
        self.playMusic(data: data!)
    }
```

Comment: Improve the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved it by myself as following:

```
func playMusic(data: Data) {

    let fileURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false).appendingPathComponent("voice.mp3")

    do {
        try data.write(to: fileURL, options: .atomic)
    } catch {
        print("Error")
        print(error)
    }


    do{

        audio = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: fileURL)
        audio.prepareToPlay()
        audio.play()
    }
    catch {
        print("Error")
    }
}
```

Comment: If that really solved your problem, mark it as **accepted** so that other people know it is the answer to such question and that you no longer in need of help with this.

Comment: There should be a check mark ✓ located below up/down voting buttons for the answer.

Comment: it says "You can accept your own answer in 2 days". I'll accept it later.